# Archimedes on hornangles?

Tags: mathematicians, archimedes

Did Archimedes ever discuss hornangles?

A hornangle (also known as angle of contingence, etc.) is the "crevice" between the circle and its tangent line at a point (from the modern viewpoint, such an "angle" would be zero).

We know that Euclid did, and that hornangles were the subject of a lively debate between Clavius and Peletier in the 16th century.  Furthermore, they were mentioned by a number of authors in the 17th century.  But what about Archimedes?

Comment: I think it is "horn angle" separated but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Mauricio, I have problems with that spelling.  A hornangle is not an "angle" in the modern sense, so it may be misleading to refer to it as "horn angle".  If one spells it together "hornangle" then one clearly refers to a different type of entity.

Comment: The English language does not necessarily work according to the laws of logic or mathematics; the commonly accepted spelling is "[horn angle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HornAngle.html)".

Comment: Not in any extant works. Cabillon wrote a detailed history of horn angles in a series of posts on the now defunct Historia Mathematica forum in 1990's, never published, unfortunately. He only mentions Euclid ([*Elements* III.16](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII16.html)) and Proclus as discussing them in antiquity. There is a short retelling in [Koshkin, Bisecting horn angles](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.09499), see also [Matos, Historical Development of the Concept of Angle](https://openjournals.libs.uga.edu/tme/article/view/1754/1662).